# How to output IBM-1027-codepage-binary-file?

Tags: mainframe, converters, codepages

My output (csv/json) from my newly-created program (using .NET framework 4.6) need to be converted to a IBM-1027-codepage-binary-file (to be imported to Japanese client's IBM mainframe), 
I've search the internet and know that [Microsoft doesn't have equivalent to IBM-1027 code page](https://www.aivosto.com/articles/charsets-codepages.html).
So how could I output a IBM-1027-codepage-binary-file if I have an UTF-8 CSV/json file in my hand?

Comment: What are the contents of the CSV/JSON file?  Ie, is it anything beyond ASCII number, letters, commas, and json delimiters?  Look at the contents of https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/reference/html/hcp_reference26.htm.

Comment: Yes there are. Kanji characters.

Comment: Are all the Kanji characters included present in the code-1027 encoding list?

Comment: Yes. As I researched. They're all included in ibm-1027 code page

Answer (score 1):

I'm asking around for other solutions, but for now, I think I'm going to have to suggest you do the conversion manually; I assume whichever language you're using allows you to do a hex conversion, at worst.  For mainframes, the codepage is usually implicit in the dataset, it isn't something that is included in the file header.

So, what you can do is build a conversion table, from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/reference/html/hcp_reference26.htm.  Grab a character from your json/csv file, convert to the appropriate hex digits, and write those hex digits to a file.  Repeat until EOF.  (Note to actually write the hex data, not the ascii representation of the hex data.)  Make sure that when the client transfers the file to their system, they perform a binary transfer.

If you wanted to get more complicated than that, you could look at enhancing/overriding part of the converter to CP500, which does exist on Microsoft Windows.  One of the design points for EBCDIC was to make doing character conversions as simple as possible, so many of the CP500 characters hex representations are the same as the CP1027, with the exception of the Kanji characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a separate answer, from a colleague; I don't have the ability to validate it, I'm afraid.

> transfer the file to the host in raw mode, just tag it as ccsid 1208
>   (edited)
>
> for uss export _BPXK_AUTOCVT=ALL
>
> oedit/obrowse handles it automatically.